# Laravel JWT unable to logout

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-9

I'm using the Laravel 9.52.5 and [php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth](https://github.com/PHP-Open-Source-Saver/jwt-auth) 2.1.0
Everything working fine but recently I found out that the logout function not working.
Due to my current repo is using for the web and api so the default is using web in `auth.php`

I had follow online forum mentioned to

1. add `JWT_SHOW_BLACKLIST_EXCEPTION=true` in my `.env` file
2. Invalidate using `JWTAuth::invalidate(JWTAuth::getToken());`
3. Basic logout with guard `Auth::guard('api')->logout()`

But none of these method is work, so is there anyone had solution to logout user?